# Convert date format to mysql time stamp

Tags: php, datetime, date, date-format

I have some dates that are returned as the following string:

```
Fri, 13 Aug 2010 01:48:47 -0400 (EDT)
```

I'd like to parse this and turn it into a datetime stamp, so like this:

```
2010-08-13 01:48:47
```

Any help would be awesome... thank you!

Comment: Be careful to ensure that all your times are converted to the same timezone if this applies to your app.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**It looks like you do NOT want the timezone to be converted.**

You can do it using [`date()`](http://php.net/date) and [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/strtotime) functions like this:

```
$date = "Fri, 13 Aug 2010 01:48:47 -0400 (EDT)";
$date = explode('-',$date);
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($date[0])); //does not use TimeZone info
```

This outputs:

> 2010-08-13 01:48:47